# issue searching database

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, phpmyadmin

Where have I gone wrong with [here?](http://gyazo.com/e2d924b3a0fe8248abfe3da6a81dbce2)

Here's my [database](http://gyazo.com/a3318eeb27cb221e78f6169f6c303712). When loaded the code throws the error 'Could not search' highlighting that I have a problem searching my database, despite connecting correctly (I believe) - How can I fix this?

I understand this is a very broad question; I'd appreciate the help as I'm trying by creating but this has my completely puzzled.

Thanks,

Comment: Questions need to be self-containing. Add all info in the question without the need for links.

Comment: You may have missing brace `}` at the end of `index.php` file

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing brace on line # 25.

Comment: Odd to receive two downvotes without comment. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. Maybe the downvoters didn't bother to check the timestamps and thought you had copied Rahil's comment. Whether the } should come at the end of the PHP section, or in a new PHP section _after_ the HTML code, requires some study, but it's definitely missing somewhere!

Comment: Thank for the quick response guys, really appreciate it!
The page loads now; however it throws the error:
'Could not find DB' - Anyone able to advise?

Thanks again